# Fancybox 2 not working

Tags: jquery, html, image, anchor, fancybox-2

I got a problem with my fancy box, for some reason it just opens the images normally when linking an anchor tag to an image. here is my code :

EDIT : Fancy box not working at all

index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'lib/classes/Db.php';
    include 'lib/classes/Switch.php';

    $Switch = new ThemeSwitch();

    $Switch->loadActiveTheme();
    $Switch->setImgPaths();

    // print '"' . $Switch->imgPath . 'home-bg.jpg"';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hertog van Baerle</title>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
      });
    </script>

    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php
          if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
            include 'inc/pages/home.php';
          } else {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            switch($page){
              case 'fotoboek':
                include 'inc/pages/fotoboek.php';
                break;
              default:
                include 'inc/pages/notfound.php';
                break;
            }
          }
        ?>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see i included a page called fotoboek.php, thats where the fancybox  tagg with my img is. but it just doesnt work, any of you guys got a clue whats wrong ?

fotoboek.php:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
    <?php
        $folderGlob = glob("gallery/img/*");
        $first = basename(reset($folderGlob));

        $last = basename(end($folderGlob));

        if(!isset($_GET['galleryPage'])){
            include 'gallery/pages/page.php';
        } else {
            $galleryPage = $_GET['galleryPage'];
            $pagePath = 'gallery/img/' . $galleryPage;

            if(in_array($pagePath, $folderGlob)){
            include 'gallery/pages/page.php';
        }
    }
?>
```

page.php :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 crop">
        <?php
            if (!isset($_GET['galleryPage'])) {
                $fileGlob = glob("gallery/img/1/*.jpg");
            } else {
                $fileGlob = glob("gallery/img/".$galleryPage."/*.jpg");
            }
            $c = 1;
            foreach($fileGlob as $file){
                if($c < 10){
                    printf('
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'">
                                <img src="'.$file.'" alt="photo" class="img-    responsive"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    ');
                }
                $c++;
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

all the filepaths are correct.

Comment: Can you include the HTML markup ?

Comment: Also: What do you want to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: it is, ill add the photoboek.php page

Comment: just add a small sample of an anchor image you want to open.

Comment: @DennisHeitinga btw any errors in your console ?

Comment: no didnt get any errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your jQuery reference first not last, if your anchor class is fancybox and it does not open then it should be related to the way the scripts are included.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

try

```
  $("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'group').fancybox({
        aspectRatio: true,
        scrolling: 'yes',
        mouseWheel: true,
        openMethod: 'zoomIn',
        closeMethod: 'zoomOut',
        nextEasing: 'easeInQuad',
        prevEasing: 'easeInQuad',
        helpers: {
            buttons: {}
        },
        beforeLoad: function () {
            //
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            //
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $(document).unbind('click.fb-start'); // unbind
        }
    }).trigger("click");
```

Comment: didnt work, so im not sure if it is the way im including the scripts

Comment: neither did adding the script

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by readding all the scripts.